# Service account to access data without being able to log into the web interface?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, service-account

I've been asked a tricky question.
Here is the schema.
A user have access to a custom web interface, no SharePoint.
He wants, through this interface, to access data on SharePoint. He has no account on SharePoint 2013.
From there, via the API, a service account will go on SharePoint and read or modify the data for the user.

The question is : can a person log into SharePoint with that service account ? Because we don't want that.

Thank you, and if I'm not clear, don't hesitate to say so.

Comment: is service account is running any app pool or any permission in SharePoint?

Comment: Well, I guess this service account should at least have some permissions on SP in order to read/modifiy those documents, yes...